# NSFetchRequest fetch object with next closest string attribute

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

Say I have 5 `Alphabet` objects with an attribute `letter` of the given letter (of type String) persisted to Core Data.

```
Alphabet.letter = "A"
Alphabet.letter = "M"
Alphabet.letter = "G"
Alphabet.letter = "T"
Alphabet.letter = "D"
```

I can get them sorted with the following:

```
let alphabetFetch = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Alphabet")
let alphabetSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "letter", ascending: true)

Alphabet.letter = "A"
Alphabet.letter = "D"
Alphabet.letter = "G"
Alphabet.letter = "M"
Alphabet.letter = "T"
```

Now I want to retrieve only the Alphabet object with the closest following `letter` value after "G" (in this example I want to retrieve the Alphabet object with the letter attribute value "M"). How would I construct a fetch request to most efficiently fetch this object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the sort descriptor, add a predicate and a fetch limit
to the request:

```
let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Alphabet")
request.sortDescriptors = [ NSSortDescriptor(key: "letter", ascending: true) ]
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "letter > %@", "G")
request.fetchLimit = 1
```

The fetch request returns an array with a single element which
is the first matching object (according to the sort descriptor), or an empty array if no such element
exists.

Comment: I have an add-on question; if you wanted to extend this functionality to always return the next value in the loop (e.g. input of "T" returns next object "A") how would you extend this request?

Comment: @Aaron: I don' think that is possible with a single fetch request. There is only a limited set of comparison methods available in Core Data fetch requests. If the above request returns an empty array then you'll have to issue another request without the predicate to get the first value.

Answer (score 1):

Create an `NSFetchRequest` with a predicate to filter items > "G" and sort ascending.

```
let letter = "G"
let letterRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"Alphabet")
letterRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "letter > %@", letter)
letterRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "letter", ascending: true)]
letterRequest.fetchLimit = 1
```